# GitHub is misspelled "Github" in the Developer Story page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, developer-story, typographical-error

I noticed a little typo in the Developer Story page: "GitHub" is incorrectly capitalized as "Github".

The typo is in two places and perhaps more: If you don't have a GitHub profile linked, then it says "Github" on your Developer Story page. And when you go to edit that section, it also says "Github" in the input form.

The typo goes away on the Developer Story page after you link your GitHub account, since it displays your GitHub username instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ouch. This has been fixed and will be up with our next prod build. For the record, I found 4 other instances of that typo in the developer story code, as input placeholders and anchor titles.

Answer (score 47):

This does look to be incorrectly spelled to me. Proof? Well, the first thing you see when you navigate to https://github.com is this:

[image]

That, to me, should be convincing enough that the correct version of the name is "GitHub", and not "Github".

Comment: also the company's legal name on record is "GitHub, Inc."

Comment: It certainly is!

Comment: Since this duskussion does exist, I can't help voicing my thought that erroneous capitalizations, or lack of them, are hardly "spelling" errors. RiGhT?

Comment: @Culme That question is discussed in [“Is incorrect capitalization considered a spelling error?” – English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26199/is-incorrect-capitalization-considered-a-spelling-error).

Comment: @Culme discussion*

Comment: @JohnSmith I thought Culme was intentionally being ironic.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I hope so :)

Comment: I have to pat myself on the back for the quality of that freehand circle.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that's not even a closed loop! But I admit there is an aesthetic to it.

Comment: ...duskussion... uhm.... yeah, yes, yes of course it was intentional! =)

Comment: I tend to write github, all lowercase. The reason: I am lazily leaving off the ".com" bit of the url. People seem to understand me just fine somehow :)

Comment: Sorry @Gimby what do you write, I can't make that out?