# Editing Tag Wikis Still Refers to Documentation

Tags: discussion, tags, documentation, tag-wiki

When editing a tag, there's still a reference to the now defunct Documentation. Shouldn't the text and text field be removed?

> Friendly name for Documentation
>
> This is a way to specify a
>   human-friendly spelling of a tag that we can use for Documentation.
>   e.g. powershell would ideally be displayed as PowerShell, and we can
>   make that happen with the help of this field.

[image]

Comment: I think they want to keep that name, because it might be useful down the road. But I certainly agree that the description of it needs to change.

Comment: This feature might be here to stay (although I'd assume they'd remove the reference to Documentation). It was discussed [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302350/323179) and the response was entirely positive.

Comment: I wonder what is the [friendly name for github](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362249/github-is-misspelled-github-in-the-developer-story-page).

Comment: Tangentially, and somewhat ironically, I am under the impression that the "tag info page" is no longer called the "tag wiki" (which was always a misnomer anyway).

Comment: NOTE: this question appears to be about something in documentation that was left in when it shouldn't have been, so I'm strongly in favor of leaving this one open.